# Laravel, routing

Tags: laravel, routes

This is my routing:

```
Route::get('/', 'StoreController@mainSite');

Route::get('/product/{id_product}', 'StoreController@showProduct');
Route::get('/kontact', 'StoreController@showContaktForm');


Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@formView')
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@formView');
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register');

Route::get('/panel', 'PanelController@mainSite');
Route::get('/panel/data', 'PanelController@formView');
Route::post('/panel/data', 'PanelController@updateData');


Route::get('/panel/orders', 'OrderController@showOrders');
Route::post('/panel/orders/add', 'OrderController@addOrder');

Route::post('/cart/add', 'CartController@addItem');
Route::post('/cart/remove', 'CartController@removeItem');
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@showItems');


Route::get('/{categoryName}', 'StoreController@showCategory');
Route::get('/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}','StoreController@showSubcategory');
```

Now i have in my view code link to add item to my cart :

```
<h4><a class="shopBtn" href="/cart/add" title="add to cart"> Add to cart </a> </h4>
```

But, when I clic on this, then I gave alert :

```
ErrorException in Category.php line 16:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

And I think, that Category is not need in this and I supose, that this a href is going into one his route :

```
Route::get('/{categoryName}', 'StoreController@showCategory');
```

Is there a possibility to fix it? Maybe add action to a href? 
I'm pretty sure that this Model which is called in my error is not connected with thing I want to do now.

My Category Model :

```
class Category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'zoo';
public $timestamps = false;

public function getCategoryId($name)
{

    $category = Category::select('id')->where('name', $name)>first();

    return $category->id;


}
```

}

But my CartController should return me this view

```
  public function addItem()
  {

   return View('cart');

 }
```

And I think It don/t get here anyway

Comment: What are the contents of `Category.php`? Is that your `StoreController`?

Comment: `/cart/add` is expecting a post request and you and passing an get request via `a href`

Comment: I think you are trying to get value where it doesn't exist, can you share category.php code?

Comment: I add everything in post (edited post )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your category routes is a catch all route. This will catch all the routes with similar path if they are not defined or defined after it. In this case the `/cart/add` path satisfies the condition for `/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}` so the `StoreController@showSubcategory` gets called. You need to remove them or move them to prevent route conflicts.

```
Route::get('/{categoryName}', 'StoreController@showCategory');
Route::get('/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}','StoreController@showSubcategory');
```

Could probably change to

```
Route::get('/category/{categoryName}', 'StoreController@showCategory');
Route::get('/category/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}','StoreController@showSubcategory');
```

You're also missing the `GET` route for `/cart/add`. You probably need these routes.

```
Route::get('/cart/add', 'CartController@addItem');
Route::post('/cart/add', 'CartController@storeItem');
```

Comment: I thought so! but I didn't know how to fix it. Now really works. Thank U!

Comment: `This will overwrite all other routes with the similar path since these are defined at the bottom.` Actually the opposite is true - because it is at the bottom, this will **only** catch any requests which did not match anything else above.  Routes are matched in order, from the top of the file.  The reason they matched in this case is bcs there was no GET route defined for that URI.  You don't need to move them, or update them, at least not to solve this problem - if you do, you will just get a 404, as there is now no route at all that matches.

Comment: @Don'tPanic but I tryed to change post to get and I still had the same problem. Change url solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Add to cart" link is a plain `<a href=''>` link, so clicking it does a `GET` request `/cart/add`.  But the only defined route for that URI is for `POST`:

```
Route::post('/cart/add', 'CartController@addItem');
```

So it does not match, and the next possible match is your wildcard `/{categoryName}` route which will catch anything.

You need to either:

- Update the add to cart link to instead do a `POST` to `/cart/add`, eg maybe add a form with an `Add to cart` button, or maybe have some JS catch the click and do an AJAX `POST`;
- *or* Add a `GET` route for `/cart/add`, and have that method handle adding products via `GET` instead of `POST`;